# How do compile assembly SSE on MAC OSX - Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, nasm, sse

in mac os mavericks, when I compile a file.asm with nasm and make the file.o, it's all ok but:

```
$nasm -f macho file.asm
$gcc -m32 file.o -o file

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "printf", referenced from:
      _main in file.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

while the same file, on any linux distribution ( I tried on Debian), it's work without problem with:

```
$nasm -f elf32 file.asm
$gcc -m32 file.o -o file
$./file
```

It's work, what is the problem in mac osx?
Furthermore, in osx, modifying the file replacing the "call printf" with "call _printf"

```
$nasm -f macho file.asm
$gcc -m32 file.o -o file
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from complessi.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
$./file
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The code is correct otherwise I would error on linux

Comment: gcc on OS X is (normally) replaced by the LLVM frontend clang. Try to build a gcc cross-compiler from the sources. [Here's a how-to](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler).

Comment: OK, it seems that OS X uses other conventions than the kernel. You may also have to link against libSystem.

Comment: Did you try to follow the error message and link with `-Wl,-no_pie`?

Comment: with: `$gcc -m32 -Wl -no_pie file.o -o file clang:  <br/>
error: unknown argument: '-no_pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]  <br/>
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future`  <br/>
replacing gcc with llvm-gcc the result is equal.

Comment: You should type it exactly as in the message, with a comma after `-Wl`